# Windows 8 app Game Animation speed increased when Laptop is on Power chord,Normal speed is seen when on battery-Reason for this behaviour required

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, createjs

The Game is developed for windows 8 app store using HTML5 and JavaScript, CreateJS is also used for most the functions.The object which moves by incrementing coordinates works normally and with normal speed as expected when the laptop is on Battery, the moment laptop is plugged to power the animation picks up speed and overall all game looks as though its fast forwarded.

Any pointers for this behavior is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using requestanimationframe to drive your game loop, then this would explain it.

This is adaptive based on power - running at 60fps on AC and 30fps on battery.

Details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/05/using-pc-hardware-more-efficiently-in-html5-new-web-performance-apis-part-1.aspx